# Excel - How to sum all Hour Log by week and by specific Task

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to make an excel spreadsheet of my working hour log to easily monitor all my task done.

Right now i have this work log tab that i manually enter all the task i done with date.

[image]

and this overview tab to sum all the logs.

[image]

How to sum all the task by weeks like show in the image?. And it possible that when i change the month it also automatically calculate the per week of logs?

Thank you in advance for helping me.

I tried to use =SUMIFS but i having problem selecting specific task.

Update:
maybe I missed something

[image]

Comment: im almost forgot in the overview total hours of log work and qa log work need to be show per week

Comment: Welcome to SO. Sounds like you may benefit from Pivot Tables. Google or it

Comment: about your update, you are missing the grouping part. You need to group the `Date` field too. Check https://trumpexcel.com/group-dates-in-pivot-tables-excel/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add 1 helper column to your data to calculate weeknum with the function [WEEKNUM](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/weeknum-function-e5c43a03-b4ab-426c-b411-b18c13c75340):

[image]

Formula in column D is:

```
=WEEKNUM(B2;2)
```

Set it up according to your needs (in my coutry first day of week is Monday)

Then create a [Pivot Table](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-pivottable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576) like the one you see on the right side of the image. This is my setup with fields:

[image]

Also, the field date is [grouped](https://trumpexcel.com/group-dates-in-pivot-tables-excel/) by month

Comment: Thank you Fox. I tried to follow what you said but it seems like I missing something the sum doesnt look same with yours.. how to add image to comment so i can show you the result

Comment: @PaulAnthonyAlvaran Don't add image in a comment. Edit your original question and add the new info you got and what problem are you facing so anyone can help :)